# {{ obj.data }} not displaying in vue template after axios get

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am trying to build a carousel using Laravel 5.6 and Vue.js. I can call the data from db, and console.log response.data. It works like expect it to. Script below.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#availability").owlCarousel();
  });

  export default {
    props: {
      areaId: null,
      tutorId: null,
    },
    data () {
      return {
        availability: []
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getAvailability () {
        var that = this;
        axios.get( '/' + this.areaId + '/' + this.tutorId + '/availability').then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data)
          that.availability = response.data;
        });
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.getAvailability();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now I would expect to be able to display the data like

{{availability.monday_begin}}

but it displays nothing, empty tags.

When I add a second .data to response, so change

```
that.availability = response.data;
```

to

```
that.availability = response.data.data;
```

The data object shows up as undefined in the vue-dev tools, and {{ availability.monday_begin }} throws an error cannot read property of undefined.

I also tried adding a v-if to the template, based on a couple different articles I read, but  nothing I tried worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is availability an array of objects or a single object? you have availability in your data function an array and your vue template as an object.

Comment: It is a single object.

Comment: Try and change the availability from an array [] to null

Comment: It broke the carousel and spit out an error from the template cannot read property of null

Comment: I think it should be a single object, with multiple properties?

Comment: You can but if you want to change the number of slides then you would need to re-do your template. I would set the `availability` as an array of objects and do a `v-for` For example `[{"link":"foo", "img":"bar"}, {"link":"foo2", "img":"bar2"}, {"link":"foo3", "img":"bar3"}]`. Then call `$("#availability").owlCarousel();` after you get your data set from the ajax call

Comment: The template will be static, number of slides shouldn't change, for now anyway. It should be just a list of the days, monday through sunday, with booleans, and strings. Eventually the boolean will be availability on that day yes/no, and string outputs for start and end times. I tried coming up with a solution using v-for, but i don't think it would work right. The response I get is formated like... {"id" : "id", "tutor_id": "id", "monday": "bool", "monday_begin": "string" "monday_end": "string", "tuesday_begin": "string".....}

Comment: Took your advice, added a v-for loop, iterating over a single object availabilities... and it worked. I am passing data through, and {{ availability.monday_begin}} returns a string. However it did break the carousel.

Comment: for the breaking did you run your jquery getAvailability() method after `that.availability = response.data;`

Comment: Yes I believe so, I have not changed anything in that script tag above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173924/discussion-between-trevor-varwig-and-dustin).